Как вставить содержимое одного docx в определенное место другого docx
Нужно вставить содержимое файла for_copy_path в файл template_path в строчку где написано {{ FOR_PASTE }}.
В обоих файлах находиться нужное форматирование, которое нужно сохранить, а также картинки, таблицы и множество разных элементов, которые не должны поплыть. В основном файле (template_path) еще имеется колонтитул, который тоже должен остаться.
Перепробовал кучу вариантов, из них практически идеально смог вставить содержимое в конец файла с помощью кода (иногда даже этим способом вставляется некорректно):
from docxcompose.composer import Composer

template_path = r'Dockx\\shablon.docx'
for_copy_path = r'Dockx\\text_for_copy.docx'
output_path = r'Dockx\\result.docx'

template_doc = Document(template_path)
for_copy_doc = Document(for_copy_path)

part1 = Document()
part2 = Document()

composer = Composer(part1)
composer.append(for_copy_doc)
composer.append(part2)

но тогда нужно делить файл вручную на несколько частей, чтобы вставить между ними нужный файл, а у меня таких шаблонов будет множество и текст нужно вставлять в разных местах. Пытался разделить файл на два в месте, где {{ FOR_PASTE }}, чтобы не делить вручную, но не могу в таком случае сохранить всё форматирование(
Буду очень благодарен если кто-то сможет помочь
Архив с файлами: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mXuKeaW7phb3iWWZ7QDZJRv_G-W406KY/view?usp=sharing
Файлы отдельно:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mUq5Bnlpe5jIHObkmBVJVYoh_6nXpNUT/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116860153917795772501&rtpof=true&sd=true
https://docs.google.com/document/d/14VAYWfFxy1ycKNJ8yxI29sBe_QcZTldr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116860153917795772501&rtpof=true&sd=true
